# Devrait-on corriger l'anglais sur ce site ? — Should we correct English mistakes here?

Tags: discussion, language

Je suis tombée sur la réponse en anglais à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/mauvais-vs-pire). De très nombreuses fautes d'anglais, certaines ont déjà été corrigées d'ailleurs.

**Mon avis** : Dans la mesure où nous sommes sur *French Language* il n'y a aucune raison de corriger l'anglais des réponses. Pour pouvoir répondre aux questions sur la langue française celui/celle qui répond doit déjà avoir une bonne connaissance du français, donc il vaut mieux qu'il/elle réponde en français s'il/elle ne pratique pas l'anglais courant. Ceux qui comprennent assez l'anglais pour pouvoir répondre à une question en anglais n'ont pas forcément les compétences pour rédiger et/ou expliquer en anglais. 
Pour me résumer je demande qu'il soit fait appel à l'autoévaluation et autodiscipline de chacun.

Et me direz-vous, si le demandeur ne comprend pas la réponse en français ? Je suggère qu'il fasse un effort : s'il est venu sur *French Language* c'est pour améliorer sa connaissance du français.  Et il pourra toujours demander de l'aide, j'ai l'impression qu'il y a de nombreux utilisateurs de *French Language* qui manient très bien les deux langues.

---

I was saying that since some people come here to learn some French, priority should be given to correct mistakes in French and that if we don't feel our English is good enough to answer in English we should use French, at least the person asking would learn some French. If he really doesn't understand the answer he can say so and someone who can speak English will translate.

Comment: +1 pour la question, mais -1 pour l'avis (nothing personnal) : Tout en encourageant à poster dans une langue suffisament maitrisée (et même malgré [cette question liée](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language?rq=1)), je pense qu'il vaut mieux corriger toutes les fautes, quelle que soit la langue.

Answer (score 4):

Je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne corrigerait pas toutes les fautes dans un message, même si ce ne sont pas des fautes de français. Évidemment on ne vient pas sur FL&U pour apprendre l'anglais, mais on corrige bien l'anglais sur [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) donc pourquoi pas ici.

Pour ce qui est de répondre en anglais ou en français aux questions en anglais, [cela a déjà été débattu](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language). Il n'y a pas de consensus, mais une préférence pour répondre en anglais aux questions en anglais dans la mesure du possible.

---

I don't see why we wouldn't correct any mistake in a post, including mistakes that are not about the French language. Of course, FL&U is the wrong place to learn English. But we correct English mistakes on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), so why not here.

With respect to whether to answer in English or in French when the question is in English, [this has already been debated](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language). There is no consensus, but a preference for answering in the language of the question when the contributor feels up to it.

---

P.S. The meta site is officially in English, because Stack Exchange staff does not speak French. Please include at least a summarized translation of your posts on meta if you can.