# Participer en français aux questions en anglais

Tags: discussion, language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answering in the other language](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language)

**Est-ce une bonne pratique de proposer une réponse en français à une question posée en anglais ?**

Je constate que c'est déjà le cas pour certaines questions. Cela peut avoir son utilité pour un francophone qui aura une réponse adéquate à une question de traduction mais qui ne serait pas à l'aise pour la restituer en anglais.